# "Wherever or Whenever"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english, orthography

Apologies for the title which sounds like the Shakira classic, but would you say "Thank you for providing help whenever possible" or "wherever possible"

Comment: LOL!  I thought of the Shakira song before reading your question!  IMO, it's more idiomatic to use "whenever" because unless the person you're thanking is physically moving from one location to another, bestowing help on-site, as needed, it's assumed that they are providing help *when* needed, hence, "whenever".

Comment: Are you thanking someone in advance for help that will be provided or thanking them for help that has already been provided?

Comment: It's perfectly normal in English to use *spatial* terms in reference to things that are actually *time-based*. As in *I'm getting to the stage of life **where** I think of space and time as two different sides of the same coin*. For most purposes, *I'll help when I can* and *I'll help where I can* are 100% equivalent.

Comment: Sorry @FumbleFingers, that sounds odd to me.  Also,  "I'll help when I can" or "I'll help where I can" means something very different than the OP's "Thank you for providing help (whenever or wherever) possible."

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: You really think that people consistently differentiate *I'll help **when** I can* and *I'll help **where** I can* on the grounds that the first is only used to mean *at those **times** when I can help,* and the second always means *at those **places** where I can help*? I can the understand *logic* of thinking that should be how people speak, but certainly in the UK that's not how we normally talk. In OP's precise context, *whenever and wherever* is effectively just "tautological emphasis" - nothing really to do with either space *or* time as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I can't speak for people, only myself, and to me, it sounds odd.

Comment: If you follow *I'll help **where** I can* to *I'll help **in the places** I can* the ***places*** in which one can help need not be spatial, but can just as readily refer to different parts of a project. This could then be re-written as *I'll help **how** I can* or *I'll help **in the ways** I can.* In this way, I'd say the difference is equivalent to the difference between *helping **whenever** possible* and *helping **however** possible.*

Comment: This is not strictly responsive to the question, so I'll use a comment. You'd be better off simply saying "Thanks for the help."  To qualify it with "wherever/whenever possible" is to draw attention to the fact that the other person did not always help, and this is an ungracious thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

**Both are valid, but they have slightly different connotations.**

*Help **whenever** possible* is, literally, requesting assistance as often as possible.

*Help **wherever** possible* is more equivalent to *Help **however** possible*, which isn't asking for a specific amount or frequency of timing on the help, merely asking for help in whatever capacity the recipient can.

Functionally, they both effectively mean, "help as much as possible," and are generally going to be interchangeable, but it is possible that the former could be read as an ongoing request, and the second as a one-time request.